# Gas ORM - class not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I was trying out Gas ORM, and have managed to auto-generate my models and now need to test them. However, I cannot seem to access the newly generated model.

I have the library autoloaded, and the config set up as:

config/gas.php

```
$config['models_path'] = array('GasModel' => APPPATH.'gas');
```

gas/useraccounts.php

```
<?php namespace GasModel;

/* This basic model has been auto-generated by the Gas ORM */

use \Gas\Core;
use \Gas\ORM;

class UserAccounts extends ORM {

    public $primary_key = 'id';

    function _init()
    {
        self::$fields = array(
            'id' => ORM::field('auto[11]'),
            ...
        );

    }
}
```

controller/user.php

```
public function test() {
    GasModel\UserAccounts::all()
}
```

Trying to access it however throws a fatal error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'GasModel\UserAccounts' not found in applications/controllers/user.php on line 28`

Can anyone help me in solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try add use of your model namespace or try add \ before GasModel

Comment: The use statement didn't change anything, nor did any amount of backslashes unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

When I used back the same namespace as the example in http://gasorm-doc.taufanaditya.com/configuration.html, which is `Model`, it started working mysteriously. I would have preferred to use my custom namespace though..